# Required JDK version for run applet

Tags: java, applet

Which JDK version is minimum required for Applet? Can it possible run the applet .jar in JDK 1.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets got this whole Java thing started and were available since JDK 1.0.

But if your applet uses classes from a later JDK you need to use that JDK version.

Comment: Thanks @wero! Which ID is most preferable for the applet? Please mentio the version also

Comment: @pampa What ID are you talking about?

Comment: @pampa: If you have a requirement that the applet needs to run in a browsers which only have e.g. a JDK 1.3 installed, you need to develop with a JDK 1.3. Else I would always go for the latest JDK version.